# Regular expression matching

Tags: regex

I want to match

```
(Not 'X')(Not 'X') XX XX XX (Not 'X')(Not 'X')
```

or

```
(Not 'X')(Not 'X') XX XX XX XX XX (Not 'X')(Not 'X')
```

etc...

```
pattern="^X^X ((XX ){2}|(XX ){4}|(XX ){6}|(XX ){8})XX ^X^X"
```

There is some problem with my pattern, Hope you can help me with that.
Thanks.

Comment: I recommend playing with https://regex101.com/ in order to find the issue.

Comment: Check out what `[]` does: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
[^X]{2} ((XX ){3}|(XX ){5})[^X]{2}
```

It matches:

```
YY XX XX XX XX XX YY
YY XX XX XX YY
```

but does not match e.g.:

```
XX XX XX XX XX
XX XX XX XX XX XX XX
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ilya Kogan for the site suggestion. and eh. for the comment
the solution is:

```
[^X][^X] ((XX ){2})+XX [^X][^X]
```